XCFramework cant find module
I have a closed source sdk i want to distribute via cocoapods.
Using internal libraries and private podspecs i can create a podspec that imports this framework and all its dependencies.  The framework has dependencies that are added via cocoapods themselves in the framework.
The framework, cocoapods, etc all work. Im now to the step where id like to close source this.
So i followed this tutorial to first turn it into an XCFramework to provide a compiled framework to give to cocoapods instead
https://abubkr-88114.medium.com/how-to-make-a-universal-framework-in-ios-xcframework-swift-baa0845baebd
 xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework './build/my-framework-name.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/My_Framework_Name.framework' \
-framework './build/my-framework-name.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/My_Framework_Name.framework' \
-output './build/my-framework-name.xcframework'

This produces a successful xcframework folder.  Now, when i add this framework to a new project to test it out before creating a podspec around it, I get errors in the .swiftinterface file such as No such module AWSCognitoIdentityProvider AWSCognitoIdentifyProvider is one of the dependencies of my framework.
How can i create a XCFramework from a library that has cocoapods dependencies?
